# How to embed JavaScript in PHP within div (in an include file)?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an image to display in a div depending on the URL of the page. This div is in an include file that gets used for all pages of the website. What I want is if it's the homepage (with or without index.php), is for the div to show the image. What I've pieced together so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = location.href

if (d="website.com" || "website.com/index.php") 
{
<img src="/images/DSLogo2.jpg" />;
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure if this is correct, or even the best way to go about it. Any help is very greatly appreciated, as I am still learning more and more each day.

Comment: [java is to javascript as car is to carpet....](http://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/561731)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = window.location.href

if (d="website.com" || "website.com/index.php") 
{
    document.write('<img src="/images/DSLogo2.jpg" />');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse `=` and `==` operator. The correct way how to code the condition is

```
if (d=="website.com" || d=="website.com/index.php")
```

Javascript is not a preprocessor, you can't usi it to create the code like in PHP. If you want to add element, you have to work with DOM:

```
<div id="target"></div>
<script>
  var d = location.href;
  var target = document.getElementById("target");
  if (d=="website.com" || d=="website.com/index.php") {
    target.innerHTML = '<img src="/images/DSLogo2.jpg"/>';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript doesn't work that way. You could use document.write with logic like that but something like this would be better:

```
if (your logic here) {
    var image = document.getElementById('my_image');
    image.src = 'some_image.jpg';
}
```

Notice that assumes you'll have a unique id on your image element. You'll want to put this logic in the document ready event or window on load.